# Model relationships in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can someone explain the meaning of the option you can use for relationships in Ember data?

for example I can have:

```
products: DS.hasMany('product', {embedded: 'always'})
```

or

```
products: DS.hasMany('product', {async: 'true'})
```

The first one tells Ember data that products records are sideloaded and the second one tells to send asynchronous GET request for products when they are needed; is that right? These two are the only options available? Is there some place where you can find more docs about relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly documentation is kind of waiting on the api to solidify. The best place for documentation right now is the transition document https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md and the source code https://github.com/emberjs/data .

Additionally `{embedded: always}` is deprecated/removed.  Now you define embedded on the serializer whilst using the EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
      comments: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
  })
```

There is more info in the source here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/embedded_records_mixin.js